# Where is git config pull.rebase true stored?

Tags: git, config, pull

I wonder where `git config pull.rebase true` will store `pull.rebase`.

I have run this exact line when I am in a specific branch:

```
git config pull.rebase true
```

Then, I use `git config -l` to list all the entries in local config file. However, I cannot see `pull.rebase` anywhere in it.

Is this variable stored somewhere else or with a different keyword?

Comment: What do you see when you run `cat .git/config` in the root of your project? Could you add the output of that command to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer to my question.

`pull rebase` is still stored in the local `.git/config` file. My config file is just too long that it does not show all. I have to enter to see more variables.

One command I found useful is `git config --show-origin --get <variable you want to find>`. This command shows where `git` finds your variable.

I used this for `pull.rebase` and confirmed with myself that it is indeed in `.git/config`.

Comment: For me this setting was stored here `C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig`  Probably during installation this was specified.

Answer (score 3):

```
git config --show-origin --get-regexp pull
```

Comment: Yes. I have just found out this too. Thank you anyway.